# How to Customize Modern UI in Windows 8 (put a skin on it)

Tags: windows-8

I remember for all the previous versions of windows there were skins to make your computer look better (task bars etc with a better design etc) in the form of skins. Is there something like this for the modern UI in windows 8 yet? I really don't like the look of it and I think I would be able to adapt to it better if it had a better look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few built in themes you can set under the settings app to change the color scheme and backgrounds for the start screen.

Also, You can adjust the look and feel of desktop mode in the same way you could in windows 7.

Anything outside of that you will need to wait for a third party app to figure it out like WindowBlinds, etc.

Comment: Aren't there things out yet? It has been arounbd in dev mode for almost a year now

Comment: The only one I know of that works great (IMO) is windowblinds, and they have not released a Windows 8 version yet, but if the release of windows 7 follows this time, It shouldn't be very long before WB and a matching SDK is released.

at that point its up to the community to produce the themes.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any "themes" but you can definitely customize the Metro display by performing these steps:

1. Launch the Metro display by pressing <kbd>WinKey</kbd>.
2. Type "customize".
3. Click "Settings" on the right hand side:

   [image]
4. Click "Customize Your Start Screen".

   [image]
5. You will then be able to change the style and color of the start screen.

Comment: Im looking for more drastic "skins" like this http://www.digitaltrends.com/web/the-re-imagined-windows-8-metro-concept-that-you-wish-was-real/ (this isn't an actual skin, just an example of a change that would be drastic)